# Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Please any one help me to solve it. I use FCM many android and ios app. But now one android and Ios app give error on FCM received but not crashing.

```
FirebaseMessaging: Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event
java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:570)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source:79)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzd.zzc(Unknown Source:26)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzh(Unknown Source:353)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.run(Unknown Source:26)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:7)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Which Firebase version are you using? Maybe upgrading will help? See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19004#issuecomment-433015992

Comment: I am using  com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging to 17.3.4